# Iterate over Rails5 model objects and render objects with a specific enum key value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following enums:

```
enum productgroup: { regular_product: 0, plaque_type: 1, plaque_size: 2, plaque_proof: 3}
```

And the following product loop:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= render 'product_row', product: product, order_item: @order_item %>
<% end %>
```

I have dozens of products with each belonging to a specific enum productgroup.  I would like to have my product loop only render those products of a specific enum grouptype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by enum by using the `where` method. Assuming the `@products` is a ActiveRecord collection, then you could something like:

```
<% @products.where(productgroup: :regular_product).each do |product| %>
  <%= render 'product_row', product: product, order_item: @order_item %>
<% end %>
```

I have used `:regular_product` as an example, but you could replace that by a variable or even a parameter chosen by the user `params[:productgroup]`.